# Learners, how often do you ask a new question vs how often you find your answer in existing questions ?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know how often you find your solution in an existing question before asking yours. The philosophy of SE is to build a library of questions, and (I think !) the primary goal is to have an already answered question to your problem rather than to answer new questions.

I understand it can't work as fine for any topic, for example puzzle or codegolf are not on that philosophy at all, but I believe French should. I'm not saying things are wrong or anything, but I'd like to know the proportion of the answers you find without asking.

The thing is with language, either you can find the solution else where, in a dictionary or on French learning sites, or the question is so specific that it the solution couldn't have been given without knowing the question. (Like when people don't see the difference between two words that a native wouldn't have linked).

I'd like to have your opinion, on if you think it's a problem or not, etc. Personally I love to answer questions and I wish there was more so it's not really a problem, but I still think about it.

Comment: I think the problem is that on French Language (it's the same on other language site - ELL for instance) a lot of learners come here and just do not search at all because they do not know how it works when they get here. The site's search engine is not that good and personally when I think a question has been asked and answered before I use google to search for an older question (key words for the question +  french.stackexchange).